# Compress JPEG image to specific quality level without using Bitmap#compress() method

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, jpeg

I want to compress a Bitmap (JPEG image) to quality `64`, the result with be stored in a byte array. Previously I can achieve this with `Bitmap#compress()` method:

```
public static byte[] compressJPEG(Bitmap bmp, int quality) {
    if (quality <= 0)
        return new byte[0];

    byte[] array = new byte[0];
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bmpStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, bmpStream);
        array = bmpStream.toByteArray();
        bmpStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return array;
}
```

But the result byte array (with the same input image file) is different when I run this on different devices. (May be because it use `nativeCompress()` internally)

After checking, I find out the different is in Huffman Table(s), SOS & image data parts, see this:
[Diff check between 2 image photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ0Yg.png)

So how can I compress JPEG image to specific quality level without using `Bitmap#compress()` method? Because I really want the result byte array to be similar in structure.

Comment: You have to write your own compression algorithm or use a cross-platform library

Comment: @emandt thank you for answer my question, so if I want to create a compressed JPEG image with similar in structure, I have 2 options: write my own compression algorithm, OR transfer entire image to server to process & send back to Android/iOS?

Comment: In few words: yes. Used algorithms could change in each OS minor/major version or implementation (i.e between Sony and Samsung devices), so if you expect "fixed data" you cannot use them.

Comment: As mentioned in your other question, I believe that if you use fixed tables (Quantization tables and Huffman tables), your method will work. You shouldn't even need the SOS (but you need the image dimensions to recreate it) or EOI, Try bundling the libjpeg native code, and encode using fixed tables. You can read about how in ["Abbreviated datastreams and multiple images"](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/blob/master/libjpeg.txt#L2301).

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of "quality level" in JPEG. It is a shorthand that some encoders use to select quantization tables. There are a number of variables in JPEG compression, including the type and breakdown of scans, samples, huffman table selection, and quantization table selection. If any of those are different in the encoder you use, you are going to get different output. It's the nature of the beast.

Comment: All I want is: reduce img size about 40-50% and the output img is similar in structure. So I can strip out `App0`, `DQT`, `DHT` as fixed header, only send `SoS` & img data (so they will send faster). Then receiver can merge the data with fixed header to build the img back.

Comment: You may need some APPn marker to define a file type, depending upon the decoder you use. YOu will need DQT and DHT markers that are actually referenced.